# Django - How to return only form validation messages rather the form itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

In a Django learning project, I want to return only the custom validation messages either as a list or tuples. But almost all tutorial I found online are utilizing the Form classes, almost similar to the following code:

```
def save(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm( request.POST )
        if form.is_valid():
            # save employee
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

Where **RegistrationForm** contains the following code:

```
from django import forms

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
first_name = forms.CharField(min_length=4)
last_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
email = forms.EmailField()
contact_no = forms.CharField(min_length=11)
gender = forms.CharField(min_length=4)
```

This validation is working, it returns the form with all validation messages. But what I want is: I want to return the validation messages, rather than the form itself. I am pretty new in Django so I can not figure out a suitable way (if there is any) how to return validation messages as a list or tuples rather as the form object.

Can anyone help to solve the issue?

Comment: you can do this easily with ModelForm instead of Form. i will provide a custome validation form in answers

Comment: The validation errors are in form.errors, is that what you need ? Read that part : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors

Answer (score 0):

this is a sample of using custom form validations error

first create your models

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class RegistrationModel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(max_digits=11)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class RegistrationModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RegistrationModel
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number')
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'first name'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'last name'}),
            'phone_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'phone number'}),
        }

    def clean(self):
        super(RegistrationModelForm, self).clean()
        first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        phone_number = self.cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
        if len(first_name) < 10:
            self._errors['first_name'] = self.error_class(
                ['first name must be 10 characters at least'])
        if len(last_name) < 10:
            self._errors['last_name'] = self.error_class(
                ['last name must be 10 characters at least'])
        if len(phone_number) < 11:
            self._errors['phone_number'] = self.error_class(
                ['phone number must be 11 digits at least'])
        return self.cleaned_data
```

finally in your view

views.py:

```
from django.contrib import messages


if RegistrationModelForm.is_valid():
    # do something
else:
    messages.warning(request, form.errors)
```

Comment: there were a mistake. now it's all good to go

Comment: Reza GH bro, thanks for your reply with the code.